# Can not find the Office 365 Videos app inside my All App list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, video

We have a SharePoint online tenant with Office E3 license, but when i access the Office 365 i can not find the Office 365 Videos app? so is this a license issue? or i need to create/configure the Office 365 portal first so users can start using it?

Here is the Apps i got:-
[image]

Comment: Office 365 video is getting replaced by 'Stream'. It might be possible that your tenant got migrated already, which began on March 1, 2020. Check the details here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/migrate-from-office-365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream [replaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/stream/migrate-from-office-365) Office 365 Video and I would suggest you use that, instead.

With that said, it is possible that newer tenants simply don't have the feature since the migration is in process already.